# Return length of string containing any characters but the given charset

Tags: c

I need to write a function which takes two `char *`, one containing a string and the other a set of characters, which returns the length of the string NOT containing any of the characters.

Example:

```
LenContainsAnyBut("abc", "def"); // returns 3
LenContainsAnyBut("abc", "b"); // returns 1
LenContainsAnyBut("x", "xyz"); // returns 0
LenContainsAnyBut("", "xyz"); // returns 0
```

Here's my implementation:

```
unsigned int LenContainsAnyBut(const char *s, const char *search_chars) {
    unsigned int len = 0;

    while (*(s + len) != '\0' {
        for (const char *search_char = search_chars; *seach_char != '\0'; ++search_char) {
            if (*search_char == *(s + len)) {
                return len;
            }
        }

        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}
```

Anything to improve? I would prefer the "array notation", i.e. `s[0]` instead of `s + 0` but it is not allowed in this assignment.

**EDIT**

Sry, somehow managed to totally screw my code >.<.

Comment: Are you asking us to grade it? We aren't your teacher - only he knows what he's looking for.

Comment: Should `LenContainsAnyBut("abc", "b")` return 2?

Comment: anyway, there's a bug. `seach_char != '\0'`? and does the program run correctly? the part that checks that the character isn't in the set (i.e. the `for` loop) looks bogus.

Comment: Are you looking for the longest substring that doesn't contain any of the characters in the set, or are you looking for the number of characters that aren't in the set?

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but you don't seem to ever increment `len` or set it to anything other than `0`... and then you return `len` (0)  if the string `s` is empty or if the first character in `s` is present in `search_chars`, otherwise you get stuck in that while loop for ever. All that given that you would fix the typos and other minor mistakes that would prevent the whole thing to compile in the first place.

Comment: the longest prefix that doesn't contain any character in the set, i think?

Comment: Hmm, I think I misunderstood the question. If it's the longest prefix, just `return strcspn(s, search_chars);` :-)

Comment: @Michal Yes, the longest substring (from the beginning) that doesn't contain any of the chars in the set. Sry but the homework itself is poorly documented :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with 8-bit chars, you can avoid the nested loops. First make sure `s` and `sc` (`search_chars`) are of type `unsigned char *` (not plain `char *`!) then:

```
unsigned char set[32] = "";
size_t l=0;
for (; *sc; sc++) set[*sc/8] |= 1U<<*sc%8;
for (; *s; s++) l += 1-(set[*s/8]>>*s%8 & 1);
```

Comment: I want to see the professor's face when the OP turns this in. (Of course, you can use `CHAR_BIT` to generalize this.)

Comment: @Chris: I like giving answers to homework problems that will scream plagiarism if the student turns them in verbatim without understanding them well enough to explain what they're doing when the instructor asks. Perhaps this is evil...

Comment: Will the string initialization for the `auto` variable `set` really be initialized to all `0`?

Comment: @nategoose: Yes. C does not have partially-initialized objects. Whenever an object is initialized at all, the part not explicitly initialized by the initializer is implicitly initialized to zero. You could use `{0}` instead of `""` but I switched to the latter because it's one character shorter.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to change is the fact that len is always 0 in your code, you should increment len after the for loop inside the while.

Other small mistake is that you're missing a 't' in the declaration of len (unsigned in should be unsigned int).

I also belive that in the for loop you are changing the pointer value itself, and that would make only the first character of s to be tested, when testing the other characters of s *search_chars will always be equal to "/0" try using an integer like len on the for loop as well

Answer (score 1):

The code as posted doesn't even compile, and with the obvious fixes, it will enter an eternal loop.

That being said, I'd write this function using `strchr()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to improve your run time for long strings and/or long exclusion sets then you could try to take advantage of the ability to use characters as array indexes, and create an array represent the set of characters that are allowed/disallowed from your strings.

If you create an array of length 256, initialize it to 1 for all elements (except for element 0, since I think you have to assume that it is always excluded because there is no way to represent it in the exclusion string because that is a C string), and then loop through your exclusion set string, casting each character in it to unsigned (characters are signed on some systems, but they need to be unsigned for this to work) and set the byte indexed by that character to 0.

At the end of this you have a lookup table that allows you to tell very quickly if a character is the end of your string, and the run time is O(n+m) rather than O(n*m).

Comment: +1 Thx for this alternative solution. I've seen something similar done in some library code but couldn't quite remember the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using this homework section to improve my limited ability to program in C .

So apologies if the question has an obvious answer ,

but where in the code is the value of len getting  incremented as characters in s are 'tested and passed'

Comment: You should not comment as an answer.  That's what the _add_  _comment_ link is for.

Comment: @nategoose: you may have 5k rep but for us poor mortals we are denied such luxuries as commenting ( excepting our own answers it seems)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply implement it as:

```
#include <string.h>

unsigned int LenContainsAnyBut(const char *s, const char *search_chars)
{
    return strcspn(s, search_chars);
}
```

...but hey, that's just me ;)